# How to initialise a collection of decorators efficiently?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns

Given a DB result set, I want to decorate all its items efficiently.

This is the way I do it currently:

```
@results = MyModel.all.map { |object| MyModelDecorator.new(object) }
```

I'm doing this all the time in my controllers, so I have to iterate over all items to decorate them, instantiating the decorator class each time.

Then in the template I'm iterating over the results again to show them. So I do 2 iterations.

Is this efficient or there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a simple method to simplify things.

```
# In the model...

class MyModel
  def decorated
    MyModelDecorator.new self
  end
end

# In the controllers...

@decorated_results = MyModel.all.map &:decorated

# In the views...

for decorated_model in @decorated_results
  <%= decorated_model.data %>
end
```

You also should not iterate over the result set twice. Eliminate the above call, and decorate things only when you really need to:

```
# In the controllers...

@results = MyModel.all

# In the views...

for model in @results
  <%= model.decorated.data %>
end
```

Also, try to determine if you really need to decorate *every single element* in the result set. Every time you do, you're creating another object; allocating memory and other such annoying stuff from a performance point of view. The less objects you create, the better.

Also, for big result sets, [operate in batches](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html).

Comment: You can also delegate methods from the model to a decorator object that gets instantiated once when its called then cached to an ivar with ||=

Comment: I would cache the decorated object: `@decorated ||= MyModelDecorator.new self`

Answer (score 0):

> Is this efficient or there is a better way to do it?

To determine the cost, you need two data.

1. The cost of your decorator's constructor
2. The number of model instances

Most decorators are simple ruby objects, and consequently have inexpensive constructors.

Ruby can instantiate millions of objects per second:

```
require 'benchmark'
puts Benchmark.measure { 1_000_000.times do Object.new end }
#=>   0.180000   0.000000   0.180000 (  0.179265)
```

Comment: The decorator is, as you said, a plain old ruby object, with no constructor. My main concern was about memory usage, since there could be tens of results to be decorated per visit. Using a plain old Rails helper would be less expensive I think...